# Get First and last Day of the year using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I want to get the start date and the Due date for a task which will be repeated Annually using Powershell Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is :

```
$today= Get-Date
$dueDate = (get-date).AddYears(1)

if ($today.DayOfWeek -eq "Monday" -and  $today.Day -le "7" -and  $today.Month -eq "1")
{
    foreach($item1 in $listSource1.Items | Where {$_["Frequency"] -eq "Annually"})
    { 
        $newItem = $listTarget.Items.Add();

        $newItem["StartDate"] = $today.ToShortDateString()
        $newItem["DueDate"] = $dueDate.ToShortDateString()
        newItem.Update()
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution @Jihen

Comment: Thnx Mohamed :)